# Cyclic Right Shift for C for an array- time exceeds-infinite loop?

Tags: c, arrays, error-handling

I ran this code and got an time exceed error, It implements cyclic right shift to an array , given array size, elements, and shift width, some help on why this is causing an execution issue would be appreciated,i'm new to this :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int n,i;

//array size input
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];

//array elements input
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

// shift amount input
int s,temp;
scanf("%d",&s);

//single right shift for S number of times
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
{
    temp=a[n-1];
    for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
    a[i]=a[i-1];
    a[0]=temp;
}

//Output of shifted array
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Do note that `int` is the only standard return type for `main()`.

Comment: Probably has to do with the nested `for` loop.  Look for a more efficient way.

Comment: You are using the same index variable `i` for both the inner and the outer nested `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked after changing the variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main changes are required in that `s` nested loop as you used same variable  in both outside and inside loops.

Corrections are marked as below:
live demo http://ideone.com/DaokVy

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()  // use properly
{
int n,i;

//array size input
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[100];    //edit

//array elements input
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

// shift amount input
int s,temp,j;
scanf("%d",&s);


for(i=0;i<s;i++)
{
temp=a[n-1];

for(j=n-1;j>0;j--) // use different variable here
  a[j]=a[j-1];

a[0]=temp;
}

//Output of shifted array
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}

return  0; // exit success
}
```

Comment: @Recurse upvote and accept if you find this helpful. thanks